# bash: how to delete last symbol

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to extract some information from bash command output:

```
uptime | awk '{print $3}'
```

When running it I get this result: `8:27,`

How can I delete the last symbol (i.e. the comma)?

Comment: Post the output from "uptime" on your machine and the expected final output you want from your script so we can give you the best answer

Comment: @EdMorton See [my anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276673/bash-how-to-delete-last-symbol/14276876#14276876) for the differing outputs of `uptime`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another variant (replacing `awk` and `sed` with `cut`):

```
# "unnecessary" echo with evil backticks to get rid of extra spaces
echo `uptime|cut -d, -f1'
```

appears to work... until the uptime reaches one day (thanks to @sudo_O for pointing out). Then the output format will include the number of days, and we'll need

```
echo `uptime|cut -d, -f2`
```

(the latter was my original answer because I tested with uptime > 24h).

UPD: both solutions don't really work: the latter prints uptime hours with no days, the former fails to extract hours because there's no comma separator before them when there is no days -- but the rest of the answer is actually proved by those failures.

The whole approach is error-prone. What happens after months and years? (I seem to recall it still shows N days, but I can err). What if uptime is ever localised? (Did they refuse to do it for the sake of existing scripts?) What does it show for 1 user, "1 user" or "1 users"? If we know all the answers, do we want to depend on them?

If our purpose is showing uptime to the user, extracting the part between 'up' and 'users' with a regular expression would do the trick:

```
uptime | sed 's/^.*up\(.*\), *[0-9]\+ *users.*$/\1/'
```

If we want to compare time or collect statistics, something like Linux-specific `/proc/uptime` will work better (the first column in `/proc/uptime` is raw uptime seconds).

Comment: Its result: `5 users. suse` 12.2

Comment: How did this get 4 upvotes, it's incorrect in the sense it prints the wrong results and the echo is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Is it better with `awk` and `sed` on the same machine? BTW, I would prefer the first value from `/proc/uptime` on Linux.

Comment: @sudo_O echo+backquotes remove whitespace. And it's no more "incorrect" than all the answers and the original idea, all broken when the uptime output format includes/omits "up N days" (my variant "works" when days are present).

Comment: [Backticks are evil](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1387/backticks-are-evil) use command substitution instead, You should have mention that point in the your answer as the OP will need `-f1` instead which **doesn't** give the required output!

Comment: @sudo_O Although I completely agree with the sentiment that `$()` notation should be used instead of backticks, backtics *are* command substitution.  They are just horrible syntax.

Comment: Much better however you `sed` script doesn't quite work, try `sed -rn 's/.*([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}),.*/\1/p'` [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276673/bash-how-to-delete-last-symbol/14276876#14276876).

Answer (score 7):

You almost had it, just the `substr` or `gsub` functions with `awk`

```
$ uptime | awk '{print substr($3,1,length($3)-1)}'
2:49

$ uptime | awk '{sub(/,/,"");print $3}'
2:49
```

No need for excess piping or incorrect use of backticks.

Better yet a more robust solution given `uptime` differing output using *(GNU)* `grep -Po "\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?=,)"`:

```
# More than one day    
$ uptime
12:46:18 up 92 days,  5:00,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
$ uptime | grep -Po "\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?=,)"
5:00

# Less than one day
$ uptime
12:47:30 up  4:24,  7 users,  load average: 0.34, 0.12, 0.07       
$ uptime | grep -Po "\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?=,)"
4:24
```

Or with `sed -rn 's/.*([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}),.*/\1/p`:

```
# More than one day
$ uptime
12:54:00 up 92 days,  5:07,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.02, 0.05
$ uptime | sed -rn 's/.*([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}),.*/\1/p'
5:07

# Less than one day 
$ uptime
12:54:55 up  4:31,  7 users,  load average: 0.07, 0.10, 0.08
$ uptime | sed -rn 's/.*([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}),.*/\1/p'
4:31
```

---

**UPDATE:** So if the `uptime` is under an hour the output if different again!?

```
$ uptime
14:46:03 up 3 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.54, 0.75, 0.36

$ uptime
14:53:40 up 11 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.48, 0.62, 0.46
```

One `regexp` to rule them all:

```
$ sed -rn 's/.*up\s+(.*),\s+[0-9]+ users.*/\1/p' file
92 days,  5:00
4:24
11 min
3 min
```

I'm assuming this handles years also!

Comment: +1 but no need for the `,$0` arg on gsub() as that's the default. It seems from other people's answers that sub() might be enough for the `uptime` output.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton clarity vs conciseness.

Comment: +1 I think this would be the right one. we should trust linux/unix machine could run longer than 1 day without reboot. :)

Comment: @Kent I think you misunderstood my last point I am saying given the case you have just booted the uptime might be displayed `0:05` for 5 minutes or it might be just `05` or `5` so I haven't tested with times under one hour of uptime.

Comment: @sudo_O I didn't misunderstand it. since I didn't see it. I upvote because your answer considered about the uptime longer than 1 day, it will make OP's awk $3 to be fail. from my point of view, OP didn't define the question well or I (you too) think too much.

Comment: @Kent I see, it was my misunderstanding of your comment sorry. Thinking *too much* is necessary for robust programming `:]`

Answer (score 4):

`uptime | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d ,`

Answer (score 2):

Given @sudo_O's sample uptime output (thanks!):

```
$ cat file
12:46:18 up 92 days,  5:00,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
12:47:30 up  4:24,  7 users,  load average: 0.34, 0.12, 0.07

$ awk -F'[ ,]+' '{print $3 (/days/?" "$4" "$5:"")}' file
92 days 5:00
4:24

$ sed 's/.*up *\(.*\), *[0-9]* users.*/\1/' file
92 days,  5:00
4:24
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`:

```
uptime | awk '{print $3}' | sed '$ s/,$//'
```

Comment: You never have to pipe `awk` into `sed`.

Comment: but why? i'm always use `awk | sed`.

Comment: Because `awk` can do whatever you want `sed` to do

Comment: @MarkEgel because you can do the whole task either using just `sed` or just `awk` both is unnecessary, a waste of a subprocess and doesn't show proficiency.

Comment: @sudo_O: Correct. But when you are not an awk guru, the job is done more quickly with awk|sed than getting lost in awk manpage. awk (or sed or whatever) is a tool, not a religion.

Comment: @mouviciel you don't need to be an awk guru to do `awk '{...; sub(/,$/,"")}` instead of `awk '{...} | sed 's/,$/,""/'` and if you use awk for the small things like this then you'll learn it quickly.

Comment: I suggest `uptime | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{print $3}'`  :)

Comment: @Kent why would that be preferable to `uptime | awk '{sub(/,/,""); print $3}'`?

Comment: @EdMorton: `awk '{...; sub(/,$/,"")}` doesn't remove trailing comma.

Comment: @mouviciel yes, it does just like the sed script I was showing the awk equivalent of.

Comment: @EdMorton you didn't get my joke. :/

Comment: @EdMorton: No, it uselessly removes trailing comma from $0. But the awk|sed equivalent replaces trailing comma by a comma followed by `""`.

Comment: @mouviciel sorry,you've lost me. ymn posted a shell script that had an awk script piped to `sed 's/,$/,""/'` so I showed that the equivalent awk function is the almost identical syntax `sub(/,$/,"")` so it's as easy to use that as the sed command. That's all. Not sure where we're disconnecting here.

Comment: @mouviciel - if you're looking for the awk-only answer to the OPs question, see sudo_O's answer.

Comment: @EdMorton in fact `awk $3` "could" be wrong. if his machine runs longer than one day.

Comment: @Kent I've no idea what uptime output looks like which is why I haven't posted an answer.

Comment: @mouviciel I wasn't championing `awk` over `sed` and I'm certainly not a `awk` guru, both are great just pick one, piping one to the other is never necessary.